# Saving to and Reading from a text file, android

Tags: java, android, java-io

I am trying to save to and read from a text file in Android. Here is part of the file that reads from the text file:

```
    Scanner fileScanner;
    String line = null;


    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"));
        while (fileScanner.hasNext() || line.contains(personName)) {
            line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        }
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s*:\\s*"));
        extraInfoTV.setText(items.get(1));
        websites = items.get(2).split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

and here is part of the file that writes to the text file:

```
public void saveButton(View v) {

    String data = getData();
    List<String> linesData;
    linesData = new ArrayList<>();
    if (data != null) for(int i = 0; i < data.split("\n").length; i++){             linesData.add(data.split("\n")[i]); }
    for (int i = 0; i < linesData.size(); i++) {
        if (linesData.get(i).contains(personName)) linesData.remove(i);
    }
    String submit = personNameTV.getText().toString() + ":" + extraInfoTV.getText().toString()
            + ":" + websitesTV.getText().toString();
    linesData.add(submit);
    String finalSubmit = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < linesData.size(); i++){
        finalSubmit += linesData.get(i) + "\n";
    }
    saveData(finalSubmit);
    Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this, PersonActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("person", personNameTV.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}

private String getData() {
    try {
        String toReturn;
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("info");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((toReturn=br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(toReturn + "\n");
        }
        fis.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return " ";
}

private void saveData(String s){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this on my test device, when I click the necessary button to save (button uses method saveButton), I don't find what I wrote when I go to the Activity that reads the text file. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a read\write permission on the manifest?
Since you have a try\catch block on the save methods the saving action might fail but you will not notice unless you look at the logcat output.
Try and remove the try\catch block from the saving method (the try\catch that responsible for the IOException) and let your method throw this exception to see if your app crashes or just take a peek at your logcat to see if it fails (you'll see the excpetion stack trace in that case...).

Comment: Which try/catch are you referring to? Please be more specific. You can tell me if it is the first block of code or the second and which exception I was catching. Thank you.

Comment: The methods bw.write() and bw.close() require me to catch the IOException. If there was a problem, e.printStackTrace() will show me the error anyways(I did not get an IOException so far).

Comment: The write & close methods requires you to HANDLE the excpetion thrown you dont have to catch it you can also declare the method as a thrower and let whoever calls this method handle the excpetion my suggestion was to "ignore" the exception temporary to see if your app have a read\write permission problem either way if youre not seeing anything on the logcat youre on the good side, however you are trying to get an absoulute path of a file you never created, you should create the file first then get a refenrce for the absoulte file use the createNewFile() method after creating a new file object

Comment: I edited my code to make sure there was no FileNotFound exception. Hopefully, now you can see the bug. @crazyPixel

Comment: @Vicky I laredy replied - you should create the file object using :File f = new File("NAME"); 
f.createNewFile();
And only then you can actually write to this file, as for now the object you are writing to is only in memory thus get garbage collected after your program "dies"